CMake can't find OpenMP when target's dependency depends on OpenMP
I'm working on 2 cmake projects (ros2 with colcon and ament).
Project A creates a shared lib that depends on OpenMP.
find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)
add_library(lib_a SHARED file_a.cpp)
target_link_libraries(lib_a OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)

And project B uses the above library.
Note that project B itself does not depend on OpenMP.
find_package(project_a REQUIRED)
add_library(lib_b SHARED file_b.cpp)
target_link_libraries(lib_b project_a::lib_a)

I can compile project A without issues.
When compiling project B I get the error:
Target "lib_b" links to target "OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX" but the target was not found. Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?

I can compile project B without issues if I add find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED) to its CMakeLists.txt.
But since project B itself doesn't depend on OpenMP I shouldn't need to do this, right??
I'm guessing I'm missing some step in project A's cmake?
How can I fix this without having to find OpenMP in project B?

target_link_libraries(lib_a PUBLIC OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX) ? Also ensure that package is found

@Swift-FridayPie I have the same error with PUBLIC. Yes the package is found correctly

Use PRIVATE instead of PUBLIC. But note that project A won't work if OpenMP is not available.

Project A should add the line find_dependency(OpenMP) to its config file (which is read upon find_package(project_a) from the project B).
